# Derivation of metric of spacetime with a point source in 2+1 dimension using ADM formalism

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, momentum, hamiltonian-formalism, adm-formalism

In "Quantum Gravity in 2+1 dimension" by S Carlip, Sec 3.1 (where the metric of a spacetime with a point source is derived, using the ADM formalism), equation 3.8 states that (this is the momentum constraint for a metric on a constant surface),

$$ \nabla_{j} \Pi^{ij} = 0 = g^{il}\partial_{k} \Pi^{k}_{l} - (1/2)g^{il}(\partial_{l}g_{jk})\Pi^{jk}. $$

There should be two terms with Christoffel connections from the covariant derivative, however this has only one. I am getting another term which I find to be non-zero. Can somebody please tell me how the other term vanishes?

Comment: [Aha, this reference](http://www.amazon.com/Quantum-Dimensions-Cambridge-Monographs-Mathematical/dp/0521545889).

Comment: This reference http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~hooft101/gthpub/Deser_Jack_tH_ThreeD_Grav_1984.pdf by Deser, jackiw and tHooft has the same thing, but the $\Pi_{12}$ looks different, I haven't read through it properly, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recall that momentum $\pi^{ij}$ is a [tensor density](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_density) in 2-space, cf. e.g. Ref. 2. In other words, $$\frac{\pi^{ij}}{\sqrt{\det g}}$$ is a symmetric (2,0) tensor. Therefore the covariant derivative is

$$(\nabla_{\ell}\pi)^{ij}~=~ \partial_{\ell} \pi^{ij} + \Gamma^i_{\ell k} \pi^{kj} + \pi^{ik}\Gamma^j_{\ell k}  -\pi^{ij} \partial_{\ell}\ln\sqrt{\det g}.$$

The contraction becomes

$$(\nabla_j\pi)^{ij}~=~ \partial_j \pi^{ij} + \Gamma^i_{jk} \pi^{kj} +  \pi^{ik}\underbrace{\left(\Gamma^j_{jk} - \partial_k\ln\sqrt{\det g}\right)}_{=0}$$
$$~=~\partial_j \pi^{ij} + g^{i\ell} \left(\partial_{j} g_{\ell k}-\frac{1}{2}\partial_{\ell} g_{jk}\right)\pi^{kj} $$
$$~=~g^{i\ell} \left( \partial_{j} \left(g_{\ell k}\pi^{kj}\right) -\frac{1}{2}\pi^{kj}\partial_{\ell} g_{jk}\right), \tag{3.8}
$$
in agreement with eq. (3.8) in Ref. 1.

References:

1. S. Carlip, [*Quantum Gravity in 2+1 Dimensions*](http://www.google.com/search?as_q=carlip+quantum+gravity+in+2+1+dimensions), Cambridge University Press, 1998, Section 3.1, p. 39.
2. C.W. Misner, K.S. Thorne, and J.A. Wheeler, *[Gravitation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitation_%28book%29),* 1973, Section 21.7, p. 521.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was treating $\pi^{ij}$ as a tensor instead of a tensor density and so I was getting wrong results.